# Cannot close Durandal modal

Tags: durandal

I've read virtually every stackoverflow question on this and still can't get it working...

I have a modal that I use as a "please wait" whilst async functions are occurring.

Viewmodel is:

```
define(['plugins/dialog', 'knockout'], function (dialog, ko) {

    var CustomModal = function () {
        var self = this;
        this.msg = ko.observable("&nbsp;Please Wait...");
    };

    CustomModal.show = function () {
        return dialog.show(new CustomModal());
    };

    CustomModal.close = function () {
        var self = this;
        dialog.close(self);
    };

    return CustomModal;
});
```

I have other modals that have an "ok" button and they close just fine, but this one is opened (and I hoped, closed) from within my main logic flow.

I "require" the modal viewmodel in my main code and this works fine to show it:

```
modalBusy.show();
```

However, this does not ever close the dialog and it's driving me nuts!

```
modalBusy.close();
```

I get no errors when debugging, but "self" in my close method is not an actual viewmodel object, just contains the

```
    var CustomModal = function () {
        var self = this;
        this.msg = ko.observable("&nbsp;Please Wait...");
    };
```

bit again and obviously that's wrong.

Comment: Check this out - http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#modal - some working examples you may be able to recreate there.  Also what version  of Durandal are you using?  I seem to remember an issue using Durandal 2.1 with Bootstrap 3 or something...

Comment: That's where I got my code from to start with. Durandal 2.0 and Bootstrap 3.0 is what I have in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to use `prototype`. Your close method should be:

```
CustomModal.prototype.close = function() {
    dialog.close(this);
};
```

The way you have it written, `close()` is a "static" method. Whereas, with `prototype`, it is a "class" method. That's why `this` isn't referencing what you expect. Using the prototype chain, `this` will reference the instantiated object.

UPDATE: Here is an example of how to close the modal from your main code that will work, but, it requires that you refactor your `show()` method.

```
define(['plugins/dialog', 'knockout'], function (dialog, ko) {
  var CustomModal = function () {
    this.msg = ko.observable("&nbsp;Please Wait...");
  };

  CustomModal.prototype.show = function () {
    return dialog.show(this);
  };

  CustomModal.prototype.close = function () {
    dialog.close(this);
  };

  return CustomModal;
});

// from your main code, you use it like this    
var modal = new modalBusy();
modal.show();

// then, whenever you want to close it
modal.close();
```

Comment: Got all excited for a minute, but no, sorry. `"TypeError: Object function () {
↵        var self = this;
↵        this.msg = ko.observable("Please Wait...");
↵    } has no method 'close'↵`

Comment: That happens on the `modalBusy.close();` line in my main code.

Comment: Sorry - could you give me an example of what you mean with that please?  Like `var myPleaseWaitModal = new modalBusy` ?

Comment: Ok, the problem is the way you are using the `close()` method in your main code. You cannot call `modalBusy.close()` from your main code because you **do not** have a reference to the object that was created. The reason why you don't is because you instantiated it inside the `show()` method with `new CustomModal()`.

Comment: Brilliant. Was just in the middle of trying different combinations in my code when you updated your answer!  That really helps me understand a couple of concepts that I've been struggling to translate to js from asp.net coding, so double thanks!